# Cloudera Manager => Clusters => Activities => MapReduce Jobs Not showing anything

Tags: postgresql, cloudera

I am having trouble using the Cloudera Manager to see the jobs that are active/finished. Previously we have had not problem doing this with the UI:

Cloudera Manager => Clusters => Activities => MapReduce Jobs.

but recently we don't see anything. I suspect that this problem is related to the activity monitor database (we use postgres as configured by the Cloudera Manager installation), but I am not sure.

I made sure of a few things:

- The cloudera-scm-server-db service working
- The password for the user amon is correct
- The health of the mgmt system in the UI is all green
- There are jobs running in the cluster and I can track them using the JobTracker simple Web page that runs on port 50070. This displays all the correct information.

But the problem still persists. Nothing appears when trying to see the MapReduce Jobs. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You might verify the timeframe within which Cloudera Manager is displaying jobs. This is configurable in the right side column (the default is only for the last 30 minutes, but you can easily change it).